# What is Creed from The Office

Tags: character, the-office

I have seen The Office multiple times, and I know how Creed's story comes to an end with the police, but I can't figure out what he actually is, as both a character and a person.

He is often saying things that are completely nonsensical like, "Hey I know you! I met you in the parking lot earlier!", etc.

Does any part of his story actually explain why he is seemingly forgetful, outside of just being old? He often forgets Andy/Jim/Pam's names, and doesn't seem to be coherent during normal conversation. Is this attributed to his encounter with the military/LSD? Is he homeless (he mentions a soup kitchen)?

I fear that this character may just be the "catch-all" for nonsense in the story, but I'd love for him to make sense as a character, if that is possible.

Comment: `Does any part of his story actually explain why he is seemingly forgetful, outside of just being old? ` Yes, he's also a weirdo.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Part of the problem with the stories of the individual characters is that many scenes were often shot, that did not make it into either the original NBC airing or the syndicated airings, and may only be available as a "DVD Extra".

While the character of "Creed Bratton" had a shockingly similar backstory to the actor that played him, though it wouldn't make sense to bill the actor each episode as himself - as the real Creed Bratton obviously didn't work in a paper supply company in Scranton.  As mentioned on the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Creed_Bratton_(character)), it was revealed in a deleted scene in (Season Two) "Booze Cruise" that Creed (the character) was also a member of "The Grass Roots", much like the actor playing the character.

Based on my perception as the events played out through The Office's stories, Creed essentially drifted for many years after being heavily involved with drugs after playing with The Grass Roots for years.  He eventually became homeless; participated in any number of strange money-making schemes, and ultimately settled on "moonlighting" as a quality control representative at Dunder-Mifflin.

Despite having gainful employment, he perhaps misses his life as the homeless drifter, which would explain his side efforts to sell high school students alcohol and fake identification.

In the end, it was perhaps Creed's background (being the "zany" out-there character) to put the relationships of the Scranton office into perspective.